# Cannot run new Cocos2d-x project for iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I used Cocos2d-x 3.2 to create a project using command as following:

```
localhost:bin and$ ./ cocos.py new HelloWorldDemo -p com.and -l cpp -d ~/Documents
-bash: ./: is a directory
localhost:bin and$ python cocos.py new HelloWorldDemo -p com.and -l cpp -d ~/Documents
Running command: new
> Copy template into /Users/and/Documents/HelloWorldDemo
> Copying cocos2d-x files...
> Rename project name from 'HelloCpp' to 'HelloWorldDemo'
> Replace the project name from 'HelloCpp' to 'HelloWorldDemo'
> Replace the project package name from 'org.cocos2dx.hellocpp' to 'com.and'
```

But when I open the project and try to build it in Xcode, it return error as following:

```
Apple Mach-O Librarian error
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

I checked the documentation on Cocos2d-x site but cannot find anything to help. Please help for it. Thanks a lot!

Regards,

Deve

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem use add all this framework to your project

```
libz.dylib
Foundation
LibObjectiveChimpmunk.a
AudioToolBox
OpenGLES
CoreText
CoreGraphics
QuartzCore
AVFoundation
UIKit
OpenAL
GLKit
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik! I try to create a new project with cocos2d-x-3.0 and it's find. I'll try your suggestion later.